# Parse PHP array of objects with jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get an array of objects with data from my database into jquery to render on a website.

ex:
example.php

```
<?php
function testFunction() {

$data = array()
$mydata = new stdClass;
$mydata->example = 'test';
$data[] = $mydata
return json_encode($data);
}

echo testFunction();
?>
```

ex
index.html

```
<script>
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'example.php',
                    data: {map: map},   
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',                 
                    success: function(response) {
                      console.log(response[0].example);
                    }
});

</script>
```

Output:

console.log(response);

["test", $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, clone: function, clean: function…]

console.log(response[0].example);

undefined

So essentially, I receive the response fine, when I log it it gives me a structure that makes sense. however I can't seem to find the correct way of accessing my objects inside the array, the example I have above only returns undefined. What is the correct syntax for this please?

Comment: can u post the response here?

Comment: Vicky, done
Dan Lee, fixed, I was just converting my code into a short example a little too fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse(response);` the response. You should be able to access it like you need then..

```
var parsed_reply = JSON.parse(response);
```

**EDIT After actually looking at the code:**

PHP

```
<?php

$data['example'] = "test";

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example.php',
                data: {map: map},   
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',                 
                success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response['example']);
                }
});

</script>
```

OUTPUT: "test"

Comment: var parsed_reply = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(parsed_reply.example);

throws: 
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: Sorry I brushed over your code quickly. You don't have a key called `example` in your response data. Your PHP function isn't returning an Indexed or Associative array, its simply returning "test". You need to json_encode a proper associative array.

Answer (score 1):

You need call `testFunction()` in example.php

```
<?php
   function testFunction() {

    $data = array()
    $mydata = new stdClass;
    $data[] = $mydata->example = 'test';

    return json_encode($data);
  }
     echo testFunction();
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I omitted that part as it is only an example, as I said I do get the response filled with data, I just don't know how to access it properly. I will edit my post for clarity tho.

Comment: Please post your output response.

Comment: console.log(response):
["test", $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, clone: function, clean: function…]
console.log(response[0].example): "undefined"

Comment: where is example object in your response?

Comment: "test" is the variable stored in example property of the mydata object?

Comment: No you can't. 'test' is the value not the key. `result[0]` will return `test`

Answer (score 1):

```
function testFunction() {

$data = array();
$mydata = new stdClass;
$mydata->example = 'test';
$data[] = (array) $mydata;
return json_encode($data);
}

echo testFunction();
```

The response is:

```
[{"example":"test"}]
```

The key here is `(array) $mydata` which converts the `stdclass` to an array before putting it in `$data`