# jQuery Ajax Success get returned Array Length?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to loop the returning Array from `PHP`. But jQuery `.length` is giving me:

```
'undefined'
```

PHP:

```
$items = array();
$items["country"] = "North Korea",
$items["fruits"] = array(
                      "apple"=>1.0,
                      "banana"=>1.2,
                      "cranberry"=>2.0,
                    );
echo json_encode( $fruits );
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items.php",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "command" : "getItems" }
}).success(function( response ) {
    alert( response.fruits.apple );
    alert( response.length );
});
```

- Here the First Alert() is ok, by returning: `"1.0"`.
- Then the Second Alert() to detect length `response.length` is returning:

  - `undefined`

Then how can i loop this Array (or) how to loop the Fruits (defined by PHP like `$items["fruits"]`) from jQuery end please?

Comment: because `response` is an object, not an array so it does not have the `length` property

Comment: in modern browsers you can use the `Object.keys().length` so `Object.keys(response).length`

Comment: try `alert( response.fruits.length );`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

simply try something like this

To do this in any ES5-compatible environment, such as Node, Chrome, IE 9+, FF 4+, or Safari 5+:

```
alert(Object.keys(response).length);
```

your code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items.php",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "command" : "getItems" }
}).success(function( response ) {
    alert( response.fruits.apple );
    alert(Object.keys(response).length); 
});
```

REFERENCE

[How to efficiently count the number of keys/properties of an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126100/how-to-efficiently-count-the-number-of-keys-properties-of-an-object-in-javascrip)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're creating an associative array on the PHP side there, which pretty much comes in as an `object` in JavaScript. No `.length` property on objects.

You can "loop" over the object keys by either invoking `Object.keys` alongside `Array.prototype.forEach` or directly using a `for..in` loop.

That could look like

```
Object.keys( response ).forEach(function( key ) {
    console.log('key name: ', key);
    console.log('value: ', response[key]);
});
```

Comment: Have a look at?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907935/parse-php-array-of-objects-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: @MarkP so the solution is to use `JSON.parse(response);`? Now i tried but still can not.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll have to convert your object to something that has length, like so:

```
var length = Object.keys(response).length
```

Note this isn't a complete solution as it doesn't work in IE8.

Another solution is adding a "count" index to your JSON object in PHP, then reading that value in your JS like so:

```
$items["fruit_count"] = count( $fruits );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you can use this to iterate through the keys

```
for(var fruitName in response.fruits)
    alert(fruitName + " => " + response.fruits[fruitName]))
```

However if you want to loop like a regular array, I suggest your PHP fruit object needs to be modified to something like the following

```
$items["fruits2"] = array(
              array("name" => "apple", "value"=>1.0),
              array("name" => "banana", "value"=>1.2),
              array("name" => "cranberry", "value"=>2.0),
            );
```

But then your Javascript will have to change to the following

```
alert( response.fruits2[0].value );
for(var i = 0; i < response.fruits2.length; i++)
    alert(response.fruits2[i].name + " => " + response.fruits2[i].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert response to array first

```
var data = Object.keys(response).map(function(_) { return response[_]; });
```

Then access the data length

```
data.length
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the given code example, you are assigning array to $items["fruits"] variable and encodeing $fruits variable. Please encode the $items["fruits"] variable and check with your coding. After changing the variable its working fine for me.

Thanks,