# How to access the data in the object returned by an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I make an AJAX request:

```
   function getdbsite(wantedid) {
      alert(wantedid);
      $.ajax({
         url: 'public/xml/xml_getdbsite.php',
         dataType: 'text',
         data: {"wantedid": wantedid},
         type: 'POST',
         success: function (data) {
            resultObj = eval(data);
            site=resultObj[0];
           // alert(site->language);  }These cause errors
           // alert(site->name);      }
            reply=resultObj[1];
         }
      });
   }
```

The server side PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$id=$_POST['wantedid'];
$site = Website::find_by_id($id);
if($site){
   $arr[0] = $site;
   $arr[1] = "OK";
}else {
   $arr[0] = "$id";
   $arr[1] = "Failed";
}
$arr = json_encode($arr);
echo("$arr");
```

AJAX responce: [{"id":"19","idlanguage":"1","name":"QI"},"OK"]

But I am unable to access the db row.

I have searched and found: 
[Parse PHP array of objects with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907935/parse-php-array-of-objects-with-jquery-ajax)

but do not understand the answers, their examples only have 1 field. Please help.

Comment: `dataType: 'text',` <-- jquery already can convert `json` string into an object for you if you specify the `json` `dataType`

Comment: `alert(site->language);  }These cause errors` <--- that's expected, there is no `->` operator in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest don't use `eval()` function for this.

Instead, explicitly set that you are going to receive JSON from the server:

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

Example:

PHP:

```
if($site){
   $arr['data'] = $site;
   $arr['message'] = "OK";
}else {
   $arr['data'] = $id;
   $arr['message'] = "Failed";
}

echo json_encode($arr);
exit;
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'public/xml/xml_getdbsite.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {"wantedid": wantedid},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {

        // use dot notation not -> arrow notation
        var data = response.data;
        var message = response.message;
        alert(message);

        alert(data.id);
        alert(data.idlanguage);

    }
});
```